# assign 100% height for div inside a div with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the height of a div to 100% of it's parent.

[image: 1]]

The band on the left looks fine but when scrolling down you notice that it is only as high as the browser window. It is supposed to have the full height of it's parent.

The content div appeared to also have the same issue, as you can tell by the background image if you scroll down. To fix this, I could remove the `height: 100%` property of the content div, but in that case, the strip on the left stops working as well because giving it 100% height requires the parent div to have a height defined.

I noticed that the Zurb foundation framework I am using sets the height of the body and html to 100%, so I overwrote this property to html, body height = auto, as I thought this might fix the issue. When I then remove the height = 100% property from my content div, it scales properly with all the result items on the right and has the correct height. But in that case, I can't assign 100% height to my search div on the left. How can I fix this issue?

My code as it is right now:

```css
#search-column {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-right: 6%;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  height: 100% !important;
}
#content {
  background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: auto;
}
html,
body {
  height: auto;
}
```

If I remove the height auto from the html and body, their height will be the height of the browser window as specified in the framework. This will break the design of the content div, which should be higher than the browser in case there are many search result divs on the right.

I could probably get it working with this height and a fixed position, but I'm looking to smoothly scroll the contents of the search div later, so it is important that the search band on the left has the full height of the content (around 2000 px in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
html, body{ height: 100%;}
```

*It will force the page to use all possible height*

---

And add this code:

```
#search-column{
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

*It will force to use that div only 100% of height*

Comment: Thanks, but that way the html and body height will be 624px, which is the height of the search column if it shouldn't be supposed to be full height, and the search column doesnt stretch to the full height of the content div (it's parent)